# How does a value in Go context get marshalled when the context is passed over to a remote service?

Tags: go, marshalling, go-context

Below is the signature of the `WithValue` func.

```
func WithValue(parent Context, key, val interface{}) Context
```

I took a look at Go official documentation but they didn't mention how a value would get marshalled when the context is passed over to a remote service.

For example, I can pass in anything as `val` such as a complex struct containing exported and un-exported fields. I wonder if my un-exported fields would ever reach the remote service. If they do, how does it work behind the scene? The whole context object gets marshalled into `[]byte` regardless of fields?

One concrete sample of a complex object is the [internal implementation](https://github.com/opentracing/basictracer-go/blob/master/span.go) of a `Span` in `opentracing`.

```
// Implements the `Span` interface. Created via tracerImpl (see
// `basictracer.New()`).
type spanImpl struct {
    tracer     *tracerImpl
    event      func(SpanEvent)
    sync.Mutex // protects the fields below
    raw        RawSpan
    // The number of logs dropped because of MaxLogsPerSpan.
    numDroppedLogs int
}
```

The above `Span` can be passed around from service to service by creating a derived context using the func below.

```
// ContextWithSpan returns a new `context.Context` that holds a reference to
// the span. If span is nil, a new context without an active span is returned.
func ContextWithSpan(ctx context.Context, span Span) context.Context {
    if span != nil {
        if tracerWithHook, ok := span.Tracer().(TracerContextWithSpanExtension); ok {
            ctx = tracerWithHook.ContextWithSpanHook(ctx, span)
        }
    }
    return context.WithValue(ctx, activeSpanKey, span)
}
```

What is the high-level protocols/rules that Go uses to pass around complex values stored in Go context? Would the `func(SpanEvent)` and the mutex really travel over the wire to the next service?

I'd be very grateful if you could explain the expected behavior or point me in the direction of some articles I've not found.

Comment: A Go context contains private data. A marshaller can only see public data. A special marshaller built *for* a context that has private data, that's implemeted by the private code that privately implements the context interface, can access the private data and *make* it public, but whether one does so or not is private to the private implementation that implements the context interface. I see that this particular package *does* implement contexts (see also https://go.dev/blog/context) but I did not delve into the details of their contexts, other than [continued]

Comment: ... to see that they have theirs carry what they call "baggage", which is a simple key-value pair map. They can stick anything they like into this "baggage". (I also see that they're using Google Protobufs for this.)

Comment: @torek I did take a look at the actual implementation of `WithValue` in Go and I only saw a simple return statement `return &valueCtx{parent, key, val}` after some if-else checks. Is this the `baggage` you're talking about? Besides, may I know where I can find the code that uses Google Protobufs?

Comment: That's for the boring standard WithValue, not for the WithValue implemented by this particular package. Look at all the source files in the repo whose link you provided (https://github.com/opentracing/basictracer-go).

Comment: @torek got it. I think you're talking about `WithBaggageItem(key, val string)` in this file (https://github.com/opentracing/basictracer-go/blob/master/context.go). I only used this package as an example. My question is about Go in general, i.e. What is the high-level protocols/rules that Go uses to pass around complex values stored in Go context? For example, from what you said, do I have to define Protobuf for my complex values if I want it to travel over the wire?

Comment: Since `context.Context` is an *interface*, you can define your own type that conforms to this interface. Once you've defined *your* type, *you* choose how to marshal anything you wish to marshal, if you wish to marshal anything. They chose to use Google Protobufs but you can use whatever you prefer.

Comment: @torek You're right that I can choose how I wish to marshal anything. However, that does not answer my question. Assuming I am calling a remote gRPC endpoint that takes a `context.Context` as an argument, how do I make sure that the remote service will get all values I put in my context? Do I have to marshal my complex objects in particular ways? Do I have to use Protobuf? What're the rules? Or all values I put inside `context.Context` will go over the wire and I don't need to do anything special at all?

Comment: You're in control. You write code. Whatever the code you write does, that's what will happen. If, on the server, you need to create a `context.Context` interface-implementing thingy, you'll have to write code to do that. You don't have to use protobufs. You *can* use protobufs. Protobufs *do not* automatically transfer context values, they just implement protobufs.

Comment: @blackgreen When you say `the Context is not marshalled as-is in a pre-determined way`, if I put a complex struct as value inside the context under a key, what will happen to the struct if I pass this context to the next service? If the behaviour is implementation-dependent, GO should at least say that somewhere in an official documentation?

Comment: @blackgreen what you said does not make sense at all. `context.WithValue` is a function provided by Golang itself. This function accepts anything as value and I can provide a complex struct as input. I am the implementor of this complex struct but I am not the implementor of `context.WithValue`. If `context.Context` can travel across API boundary according to Go specs, the implementor of `context.WithValue` should set the rules for what kind of values it can accepts to meet this spec requirement. Only then, I, as implementor of the complex object, know how to implement it properly.

Comment: @blackgreen `The KV pairs could become HTTP headers, gRPC/HTTP2 metadata, trailers, whatever.` => If so, instead of accepting value as `interface{}`, shouldn't Go ask for a specific interface value that has some particular methods that Go can use to marshal into the right `thing` that each kind of channel (e.g. HTTP, gRPC) expects?